# image load event randomly firing in IE7/8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, load, internet-explorer-7

Situation:

I am resizing / preloading images with javascript before showing them on the page.

Problem:

ie7 / 8 tend to randomy fire the load event for some images and not for others (this is completely random and different on every refresh)

Code:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".daImg").hide();
$("figure").each(function(){
    $(this).append('<div class="loader"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif"></div>');
    var afb = $(this).find(".daImg");
    afb.load(function(){
    console.log("loaded");          
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".loader").remove();
    if($(this).parent().parent().parent().is(".last")){
        if(afb.height() > 280){
            var w = (afb.width()/afb.height())*280
            afb.css("width",w);
            afb.css("height","280px");
        }
    } else {
        if(afb.height() > 245){
            var w = (afb.width()/afb.height())*245
            afb.css("width",w);
            afb.css("height","245");
        }
    }
    afb.css("left","50%");
    afb.css("margin-left","-"+afb.width()/2+"px");
    afb.fadeIn();
    })
});
}
```

HTML

```
 <figure class="left">                      
<a href="foobar.html">
    <div class="imageWrap">
        <img class="daImg"  src="foo-bar.png" alt="foobar" />
    </div>
    <figcaption class="cufonize"><span class="decorated">foobar</span><br> 
        <span class="price">99</span>
    </figcaption>
</a>
```

```
<figure class="left">                       
<a href="foobar.html">
    <div class="imageWrap">
        <img class="daImg"  src="foo-bar.png" alt="foobar" />
    </div>
    <figcaption class="cufonize"><span class="decorated">foobar</span><br> 
        <span class="price">99</span>
    </figcaption>
</a>
```

```
<figure class="left">                       
<a href="foobar.html">
    <div class="imageWrap">
        <img class="daImg"  src="foo-bar.png" alt="foobar" />
    </div>
    <figcaption class="cufonize"><span class="decorated">foobar</span><br> 
        <span class="price">99</span>
    </figcaption>
</a>
```

```
<figure class="left">                       
<a href="foobar.html">
    <div class="imageWrap">
        <img class="daImg"  src="foo-bar.png" alt="foobar" />
    </div>
    <figcaption class="cufonize"><span class="decorated">foobar</span><br> 
        <span class="price">99</span>
    </figcaption>
</a>
```

```
<figure class="left">                       
<a href="foobar.html">
    <div class="imageWrap">
        <img class="daImg"  src="foo-bar.png" alt="foobar" />
    </div>
    <figcaption class="cufonize"><span class="decorated">foobar</span><br> 
        <span class="price">99</span>
    </figcaption>
</a>
```

If anyone could shed some light of what is going on here, I'd appreciate it!

Note: This issue has nothing to do with caching as I am adding time-stamps to all images in my actual code.

Comment: it is a know problem with IE, onload do not fire for cached images

Comment: `.closest(selector)` will help clean up your code from `.parent().parent().parent()` etc

Comment: They are not cached. They actually do load, the event just doesn't seem to go off.

Comment: To add to venimus, if that is the case, put a random querystring on the end of your image path to force reload in IE

Comment: Thats the system I currently have in place for preventing caching, adding a timestamp in the query, see "Note:"

Comment: IE loads the images, but may not fire the event itslef. you could try to use `onreadystatechange` event for the images. Also there is a known problem with the event if you modify the dom while images are loading. I think you could try without the .loader and see what happens

Comment: I have tried without the loader div and this somewhat improves the amount of images coming through. This would mean they are loading before they get to the point in the script where the eventhandler is hooked. I don't understand how uncached images from a server can load faster then javascript though...

Comment: yes this is the main reason. IE loads the image when parser finds a src attribute and it happens before the event is hooked.  a common solution for the problem is to create the image without the src attribute, then hook the event, then set the src attribute which will fire the event. but i suppose in your case this is not really possible

Comment: Could always stuff the src in data-src and move it over. Possibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try a different approach in your case

use css

```
.daImg {
   display:none;
}
```

then hook your image resizing script on $(window).load();
and manipulate all images :not(:visible) at once

you could also duplicate this for the rest browsers to the img.load event but for images that are not already visible. i mean your selector to be `var afb = $(this).find(".daImg:not(:visible)")`;

in this case IE all images that are not processed by the other event will get processed there

Comment: well when it is IE involved usually the solution is not pretty :)